# How can I refresh second select option when first select option is changed?

Tags: javascript, php

How can I refresh second select option when first select option is changed?

I am generating the array here for patient_code2:

```
    //GENERATE NUMBERS FOR CYCLE
    function patsient(selector) {
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 99; i++) {
            var text = '0' + i;
            selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 2, 2));
        }

    }
    patsient(document.getElementById("patient_code2"));
```

I am generating the array for patient_code here:

```
    function myFunction(selector) {
        var i;
        for (i = 1; i <= 999; i++) {
            var text = '00' + i;
            selector.options[i - 1] = new Option(text.substr(text.length - 3, 3));
        }
    }
    //usage:
    myFunction(document.getElementById("patient_code"));
```

Here I am inserting the last value from database to the field:

```
    //INSERT THE VALUE FROM DATABASE
    var tsykkel_id = '<?php foreach ($tsykkel_id as $row){echo $row['patsiendi_tsykkel'];}?>';
    $('#patient_code2')[0].options[parseInt(tsykkel_id)].selected = true;

        $(document).ready().on('change', '#patient_code2', function () {
            var index = $('option:selected', $(this)).index();
            $('option', $(this)).each(function (i, x) {
                if (i < index) { $(this).remove(); }
            });
        });
```

HTML

```
                    <select name="patient_code" data-placeholder="" id="patient_code" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
                    </select>

                    <label class="control-label">Tsükkel:</label>
                    <select name="patient_code2" data-placeholder="" id="patient_code2" class="chosen-select form-control" tabindex="2">
                    </select>
```

So lets say that person chooses 002 from the first  then the second  should start from 01 again.

Comment: Do you want it done server side or client side?

Comment: you need only `javascript`? from what i see, you are also using jQuery here `$('#patient_code2')`?

Comment: @OlaviSau it doesn't really matter. I have tried both ways and nothing works. I would prefer client side so the values stay in the database-

Comment: @roullie, javascript and jquery both are fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this then.  Code is tested.

```
$(document).ready().on('change','#patient_code2',function(){
    var index = $('option:selected',$(this)).index();
    $('option',$(this)).each(function(i,x){
        if(i<index){$(this).remove();}
    });
    $('select#patient_code').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/69j94ro6/2/

Comment: This removes all of the, expect the one from DB. What I would like is that it still displays 07,08,09 etc. Only remove the options before the 06 (as an example).

Comment: Still only displays the value from database.

Comment: LEGEND! works. if you can help me with one more thing, I will be forever grateful for you! I have another <select> as well. At the moment it is 001 but let's say that person chooses 002 from the first selection, is there any way to refresh the second <select>?

Comment: update your question and add your new question to it. and the example

Comment: roullie could you add '#patient_code2  > option:selected' otherwise it parses all the options on the page.

Comment: @OlaviSau no, it wont select all `<select>` since it has a 2nd argument`$(this)` which is referring to `#patient_code2`

Comment: I'm going to sleep, that moment when your blind.

Comment: @OlaviSau you can try it here i created two select for examples http://jsfiddle.net/roullie666/69j94ro6/

Comment: @roullie yes. the naming convention sucks. sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can just start printing after the match has been found. I am writing both ways since you asked?

For javascript version use roullie's no point duplicating.

```
<?php 
$flag = false;

foreach ($tsykkel_id as $row) {
    if ($selected) {
        $flag = true;
    }
    if ($flag) {
        $row['patsiendi_tsykkel'];
    }
}?>
```

Comment: Why is `$flag = false` outside the `<?php ?>` tag?

How does JavaScript access to the data from PHP in this example?

Comment: Oh that... a mistake :D